# Accessing a File from Distributed Cache in Pig UDF Java class, Amazon EMR

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, amazon-emr, distributed-cache, udf

I am trying to access a file (sample.txt) in UDF. I want to put that file in distributed cache and use it from there. I am using amazon EMR to run the Pig job. I am copying the file (sample.txt) to HDFS using EMR bootstrap-action while creating cluster.

**bootstrap.sh**(copies file from s3 to hdfs)

```
hadoop fs -copyToLocal s3n://s3_path/sample.txt /mnt/sample.txt
```

---

**UsingSample.java**(UDF that uses sample.txt)

```
public class UsingSample extends EvalFunc<String>{

public String useSampleText(String str) throws Exception{
    File  sampleFile = new File(“./sample”);

    //do something with sampleFile

}

@Override
public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
    if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
        return null;

    String str = (String) input.get(0);
    String result = "";
    try {
        result = useSampleText(str);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

public List<String> getCacheFiles() { 
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(1); 
   list.add("/mnt/sample.txt#sample"); // not sure if the path I am passing is correct
   return list; 
}
```

}

---

**create_cluster.sh**(script that creates the cluster and executes the Pig script)

```
aws emr create-cluster 

--auto-terminate 

--name "sample cluster" 

--ami-version 3.8.0  

--enable-debugging 

--applications Name=Pig 

--use-default-roles 

--instance-type m1.large 

--instance-count 3 

--steps Type=PIG,Name="Pig Program",ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Args=[-f,$S3_PIG_SCRIPT_URL,-p,INPUT=$INPUT,-p,OUTPUT=$OUTPUT] 

--bootstrap-action Path=s3://s3_bootstrapscript_path/bootstrap.sh
```

---

The error which I am getting is FileNotFound exception when trying to access sample.txt in getCacheFiles().

I am using:

`Hadoop 2.4
Pig 0.12`

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try to copy the file to HDFS using the following command:

```
Hadoop distcp s3n://bucket/file /home/filelocation
```

then check the existence of the file on HDFS using:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /home/filelocation
```